# While loop in JS slows down browser

Tags: javascript, firefox, while-loop

I am writing on a code that should guess a number the user entered and return a paragraph with a string and the number of tries the script needed to get the number. Nothing too fancy. The problem is that as soon as I start the page on firefox, it basically crashes down and I don't know why.

Thanks for the help.

This is my code:

```
    <input id="guess" placeholder="Your Number">
    <button id="guessButton">Guess it!</button>
    <br>
    <div id="scriptOutput"></div>

    <script>
        var myNumber = document.getElementById("guess").value
        var guess = false
        var scriptGuess = Math.random()
        scriptGuess = scriptGuess*6
        scriptGuess = Math.floor(scriptGuess)
        var guessCount = 1


        document.getElementById("guessButton").onclick = function() {

            while (guess == false) {

                if (myNumber == scriptGuess) {
                    document.getElementById("scriptOutput").innerHTML = "<p>" + "I got it after" + guessCount + "times!" + "</p>";
                    guess = true;

                }else {
                    guessCount ++;

                }
            }
        }

    </script>

</body>
```

Comment: You have an infinite loop, and thus the browser eventually hangs on "unresponsive". This answers the "why" part. The below answer by @SundayCode seems would solve your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are defining `scriptGuess` before the while loop, thus, each time the while loop runs, `scriptGuess` isn't changing. This is creating an infinite loop.

Try adding the guess logic inside of the while loop. This way, a new `scriptGuess` value is initialized every instance of the while loop:

```
<body>
    <input id="guess" placeholder="Your Number">
    <button id="guessButton">Guess it!</button>
    <br>
    <div id="scriptOutput"></div>

    <script>
        var myNumber = document.getElementById("guess").value
        var guess = false
        var guessCount = 1


        document.getElementById("guessButton").onclick = function () {

            while (guess == false) {
                var scriptGuess = Math.random()
                scriptGuess = scriptGuess * 6
                scriptGuess = Math.floor(scriptGuess)

                if (myNumber == scriptGuess) {
                    document.getElementById("scriptOutput").innerHTML = "<p>" + "I got it after" + guessCount + "times!" + "</p>";
                    guess = true;

                } else {
                    guessCount++;

                }
            }
        }

    </script>

</body>
```

However, I still think you are going to run into problems with time complexity. This is going to take a lot of time to guess a user's inputted number, especially without a pre determined range.

Comment: Do you also know why this code only works once and has to be reloaded as a page to work again? How could I make it reusable?